# Clone figure in Matlab - with properties and data

Tags: matlab

I write a script in matlab, which produces figures out a set of data.

The figures are supposed to rather similar with respect to formating, and each of them is ought to display a set of data ( it is graph embedded in a 3d-domain ). Each of these figures is ought furthermore to display a set of particles within that 3d-domain.

So i would like to create the first figure, then make several copies of it, and put in the data sets. However, I do not know, how I can create clones of a figure in Matlab in a simple way.

Do you know, how I can clone figures?

The online documentation didn't help. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

MATLAB's built-in function [copyobj](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/copyobj.html) should also work. Here's an example:

```
peaks;
f2=copyobj(gcf,0);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can put the code you use to generate your base figure into a function, then call that function multiple times to create multiple copies of your base figure. You will want to return the [graphics handles](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/learn_matlab/f3-15974.html) for those figures (and probably their axes) as outputs from the function in order to modify each with a different set of plotted data. For example, this function makes a 500-by-500 pixel figure positioned 100 pixels in from the left and bottom of the screen with a red background and one axes with a given set of input data plotted on it:

```
function [hFigure,hAxes] = make_my_figure(dataX,dataY)
  hFigure = figure('Color','r','Position',[100 100 500 500]);  %# Make figure
  hAxes = axes('Parent',hFigure);                              %# Make axes
  plot(hAxes,dataX,dataY);  %# Plot the data
  hold(hAxes,'on');         %# Subsequent plots won't replace existing data
end
```

With the above function saved to an [m-file](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f7-41453.html) on your [MATLAB path](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_env/br7ppws-1.html), you can make three copies of the figure by calling `make_my_figure` three times with the same set of input data and storing the handles it returns in separate variables:

```
x = rand(1,100);
y = rand(1,100);
[hFigure1,hAxes1] = make_my_figure(x,y);
[hFigure2,hAxes2] = make_my_figure(x,y);
[hFigure3,hAxes3] = make_my_figure(x,y);
```

And you can add data to the axes of the second figure like so:

```
plot(hAxes2,rand(1,100),rand(1,100));
```

Answer (score 2):

A convenient way to generate a function that sets all the parameters such that the figure (as in [@gnovice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677853/clone-figure-in-matlab-with-properties-and-data/3678422#3678422)'s post) will look just right is to create the first figure with all the data (including the 3D points) and all the formatting, and then choose from the FILE-menu the command [GENERATE M-FILE...](http://blogs.mathworks.com/desktop/2010/04/19/reproducing-figures/) (have a look at the tutorial linked here).

This creates a function that you can save on the Matlab path, and which you can later call with new input to create an exact clone of the first figure with new data.