# How can reuse figure in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, figure

I would like to reuse a figure I create in Matlab script.

```
fig1 = figure;
plot(...);
title(...);
% ...
% now I would like to plot fig1 again with a different title
% ...
% now I would like to plot fig1 again as a subplot in a 2x2 grid
```

How can I do that without code duplication?

Can I use the figure object? Or perhaps save the plot object somehow?

Comment: Yes, there exists a technique known at leas since 60' - put recurring code into a (sub)function. For details consult MATLAB Help http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/subplot.html

Comment: @Mikhail: thanks, I know about functions, but I thought perhaps there is a way to use the object itself.

Comment: OK, then consult this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677853/clone-figure-in-matlab-with-properties-and-data

Comment: this one is also relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4008880/97160

Comment: Most people are missing the point of the question. He obviously does not want to have to use the plotting functions twice. Some of us are dealing with very large data sets and even a simple plot can be time-consuming. I think the question is about making the plot once without visualising it but storing it in a variable so that it can be visualised at a later time on demand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`plot` and friends all work on the current axes, so just put all of that code (not including `figure`) into a separate (sub)function, then call it after setting up a new figure/title/subplot.

If you can't do this for whatever reason, check out the example at the bottom of the page [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/copyobj.html).

Answer (score 1):

> fig1 = figure;
>
> p1=plot(...);
>
> title('something');
>
> % ...
>
> % now I would like to plot fig1 again with a different title
>
> title('something else'); % This will replace the old title with the new one 'something_else'.
>
> % now I would like to plot fig1 again as a subplot in a 2x2 grid
>
> delete(p1);
>
> subplot(2,2,1);
>
> p1=plot(...);

OR, you can just refresh your figure (without closing it and opening another one...) by typing:

> clf reset

This will reset all figure properties, such as background color.  Then, you can re-plot whatever you like.